# Does integrating out a variable in a two-variable measurable function produce a measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

This problem is not a mere consequence of Fubini’s Theorem, so I thought that it would be suitable for posting here on MSE.

Let $ (X,\Sigma,\mu) $ and $ (Y,\text{T},\nu) $ denote $ \sigma $-finite measure spaces. Suppose $ F $ is a $ (\Sigma \otimes \text{T}) $-measurable function with the property that for each $ x \in X $, the function $ F(x,\cdot): Y \to \mathbb{C} $ is $ \nu $-integrable. Is it then necessarily true that the function $ G: X \to \mathbb{C} $ defined by
$$
\forall x \in X: \quad G(x) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \int_{Y} f(x,y) ~ \mathrm{d}{\nu(y)}
$$
is $ \Sigma $-measurable? Note that $ F $ is not assumed to be an element of $ {L^{1}}(X \times Y,\Sigma \otimes \text{T},\mu \otimes \nu) $.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This follows by an application of the Fubini-Tonelli theorem on the positive/negative parts of the real/imaginary parts of $f$.

Note that for Fubini-**Tonelli**, non-negativity (together with measurability) is enough, you do not need $f \in L^1$.

Comment: You’re right. Tonelli’s Theorem slipped my mind.